# Why doesn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Question 3 of section 11.7 in Steward's sixth edition of Early Transcendentals asks:

> Test the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n}$ for convergence or divergence.

According to [this](http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780495011668-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-6th-edition/722/#exercises) site, this series diverges. However, I continue to get the result that this series converges, as follows:

First we simplify the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n^n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-2)^{2}}{n}\right)^n$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4}{n}\right)^n$$

Then we use the root test, which states that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}} < 1$, the series converges.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{4}{n} = 0 < 1$$

Thus, the series converges.

My question is, where is the error in my proof? Or rather, is it the site that is wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** My apologies, I read the question number wrong - the site does say that this converges.

Comment: Question 3 on the link you gave is about $\sum (-1)^n\frac n{n+2}$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that - I guess the question must have been placed incorrectly, as http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780495011668-stewart-calculus-early-transcendentals-6th-edition/722/#exercises links "Question 3" to that series instead.

Comment: Annnddd I just realized that I read the question number incorrectly; I didn't realize the questions were set up in sets of two columns. Whoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the series does converge.

Comment: And lickety-split since the terms go to zero very fast.